# Spring Boot Exception Handler get all Exceptions at once

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

Is there a way to catch all exceptions at once that are thrown from a web request in a Spring Boot Exception Handler? I know I can catch an array of Exception types in my method annotated with `@ExceptionHandler` but it's not the types I'm talking about. I need something like a list of Exception objects. I already tried

```
@@ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class })
@ResponseBody
private Error handleException(final List<Exception> ex, WebRequest request) {
...
}
```

but Spring is not able to find a suitable resolver for that:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [0] in private com.example.demo.model.Error com.example.demo.exception.MyExceptionHandler.handleException(java.util.List<java.lang.Exception>,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest): No suitable resolver
```

With catching only one Throwable object it works fine:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class })
@ResponseBody
private Error handleException(final Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
...
}
```

But what to do if I have different parameter violations like e.g. a `ConstraintViolationException` and a `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException` in the same request?

If it's not possible to process a list of exceptions, how can I satisfy RFC-7807 (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807)? Which means: How can I collect all invalid parameters, no matter what's the causing exception?

Comment: Your request will have only one exception at any moment, not multiple

Comment: If you have several errors, just one of them (the first according some logic) will throw an exception, not all at once. Do you want a method that captures all possible exceptions in your spring boot app?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies. Sounds like Spring Boot lacks in this functionality. According to the RFC 7807 definition (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807) it would be useful to provide the "invalid-params" field in 400 Bad Request responses filled with all violated parameters, no matter what's the cause. Is there a way in Spring Boot for realizing this? Do I have to implement something different and not Exception Handlers?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<String> handle(Exception ex) {
    // ...
}
```

you will catch most general exception. Then you can get suppressed
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Throwable.html#getSuppressed()

you cant throw more than one exception at once

Comment: `getSupressed()` returns empty arrays in case of Exception Handlers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the annotation, but to catch multiple exceptions you do (remember that the first matching `catch` block will execute):

```
@ResponseBody
public MyError handleException(List<Throwable> exceptions, WebRequest request) {
    try {
        //...
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        //...
    } catch (MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException e) {
        //...
    }
}
```